# Laravel - root directory routing behaves strangely in a nested route group

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have the following route definition in Laravel 5. When I group the routes in the following way, it seems the route `admin.proposals.home` will not work if I provide `"/"` as the get path, and will work if something trailing (like `home`) is provided:

```
/** 
 *  Routes for system administrators.
*/
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'admin'], function()
{
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'people'], function() 
    {
        Route::get('/', ['as' => 'admin.people.home', 'uses' => 'PersonController@index']);
        Route::get('/profile/{userName}', ['as' => 'admin.person.profile', 'uses' => 'PersonController@view']);
        Route::get('/organization/{id}', ['as' => 'admin.people.organization', 'uses' => 'PersonController@indexByOrganization']);
    });

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'projects'], function() 
    {
        Route::get('/', ['as' => 'admin.projects.home', 'uses' => 'ProjectController@index']);
        Route::get('/{projectId}', ['as' => 'admin.project.view', 'uses' => 'ProjectController@view']);

        Route::group(['prefix' => 'proposals'], function() 
        {
            //problematic line below
            Route::get('/home', ['as' => 'admin.proposals.home', 'uses' => 'ProposalController@index']);   
            Route::get('/{proposalId}', ['as' => 'admin.proposal.view', 'uses' => 'ProposalController@view']);
        });

    });

});
```

Specifically, if I change the line:

```
Route::get('/home', ['as' => 'admin.proposals.home', 
           'uses' => 'ProposalController@index'
          ]);
```

To:

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'admin.proposals.home', 
            'uses' => 'ProposalController@index'
          ]);
```

I got an error saying:

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View:  ... \views\admin\projects\view.blade.php)
```

But, the `admin.proposals.home` route points to the controllers `index()` method and has nothing to do with the `view.blad.php`.

Changing the path back to `get('/home')` works perfectly.

What is it that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a `Route` position order problem.

Since you have the route for the URI `admin/projects/` as `admin.project.home`, and after that `admin/projects/{projectId}` it takes precedence over the route `admin/projects/proposals/`

Laravel takes `proposals` as the `projectId`.

```
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'projects'], function() 
    {
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'proposals'], function() 
        {
            //problematic line below
            Route::get('/', ['as' => 'admin.proposals.home', 'uses' => 'ProposalController@index']);   
            Route::get('/{proposalId}', ['as' => 'admin.proposal.view', 'uses' => 'ProposalController@view']);
        });
        Route::get('/', ['as' => 'admin.projects.home', 'uses' => 'ProjectController@index']);
        Route::get('/{projectId}', ['as' => 'admin.project.view', 'uses' => 'ProjectController@view']);



    });
```

Try this order and let me know what you get. But purely it's a route order problem.

Comment: Thanks! Now I think I understand the cause of this problem. Will try and update you!

Comment: Thank you, it now works like a charm. This helps a lot in understanding how routing works.